# Jump to file without modifying jump list

Tags: vim

I'm writing a TAGS-like plugin. It should be able to jump to the given file, line, and column.

I use `:edit` to jump to the right file, and then `G`/`|` to jump to the right location (as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19195792/110081)).

My problem is that `:edit` adds the beginning of the target file to the jump list, and thus I end up with two locations in the jump list instead of one.

Can I prevent `:edit` from modifying the jump list, or maybe make it open the target file at the right location?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `:keepjumps edit` to avoid adding to the jump list.

Instead of the `G` command, use the more low-level `:call cursor(...)` function; it doesn't affect the jump list. The `|` command for horizontal positioning is fine.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore, at least on vim or neovim head, both installed using brew