# How to remove buffer from jumplist in vim

Tags: vim, buffer

How could I delete a buffer and remove it from the jumplist? so that the next time I hit `<CTRL-o>` or `<CTRL-i>` it doesn't open it again.

Comment: If you came to this question because your script adds undesired jumps to the jumplist, use `keepjumps` before your command, as explained in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19925591/jump-to-file-without-modifying-jump-list).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do that you should use one of the built-in commands provided by vim

`:bdelete` that only closes the buffer and replace it with the one next to it in the jumplist unless there are changed that has not been saved, if you want to delete the buffer and discard the changes `:bdelete!` is what should be used.

The problem with `:bdelete[!]` is that only the buffer will be deleted but everything else related to it will stay there like it's position in the `jumplit` and the marks that registered on it and so on.

So the second command that I find very powerful is `:bwipeout[!]` which will remove the buffer completely and all the metadata related to it.

With both these commands you can specify counters and ranges, for example:

> to delete all buffers use `:%bd[elete][!]`
>
> to delete all buffers from buffer number 4 to the last one use `:4,$bdelete[!]` and so on.

the same goes for `:bwipeout[!]`